# Postgresql WITH statement used with a c function which requires sql text as parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

I am trying to make the following query using WITH statement in POSTGRESQL:

```
WITH catchment AS (
                SELECT *  FROM  ..   -- Some time consuming join statement
     ),
     catchment10 AS (
                SELECT * FROM pgr_pointsaspolygon('SELECT * FROM catchment where cost < 10000')
     ),
     catchment20 AS (
                SELECT * FROM pgr_pointsaspolygon('SELECT * FROM catchment where cost < 20000')
     ),
     catchment30 AS (
                SELECT * FROM pgr_pointsaspolygon('SELECT * FROM catchment where cost < 30000')
     )
SELECT * FROM  catchment10
UNION
SELECT * FROM  catchment20
UNION
SELECT * FROM  catchment30
```

The problem is that the pgr_pointsaspolygon() function calls pgr_alphashape() function which uses some c libraries:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pgr_alphashape(IN sql text, OUT x double precision, OUT y double precision)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
'$libdir/librouting_dd', 'alphashape'
  LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 1
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION pgr_alphashape(text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The pgr_alphashape requires an sql statement to work but when I pass the catchment table from the WITH clause it gives the following error:

```
      ERROR:  relation "catchment" does not exist
```

Is there any other way or a way to correct this error so that the catchment table is not computed 3 times but can be passed to the pgr_pointsaspolygon function?

Comment: Can you do this in two steps and create catchment as a temp table first?

Comment: Your version of Postgres? The problematic part is the function `pgr_pointsaspolygon()`, taking a string to execute as code, which is almost always a bad idea. It opens the floodgates for SQL injection and is bad for performance. I see on the internets that the function is from [pgRouting](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/driving_distance/doc/dd_points_as_polygon.html), so you may not be able to change that ... You should have mentioned that, too, in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are obviously working with functions provided by a third party, your only option is a temporary table. Use [`CREATE TABLE AS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtableas.html)  with `ON COMMIT DROP` to avoid conflicts with multiple calls in the same session.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMP TABLE catchment ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT *  FROM  ..   -- Some time consuming join statement
;

SELECT * FROM pgr_pointsaspolygon('SELECT * FROM catchment WHERE cost < 10000')
UNION ALL  -- Presuming we do not want to eliminate dupes?
SELECT * FROM pgr_pointsaspolygon('SELECT * FROM catchment WHERE cost < 20000')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM pgr_pointsaspolygon('SELECT * FROM catchment WHERE cost < 30000')
COMMIT;
```